# Can I use UK Super Priority visa service and how long does it take?

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals

My UK visit visa has been refused. If I reapply through Super Priority visa service, it says:

> If your application is not straightforward, it may not be possible to meet this timescale.

If so, within how many days would I get a decision?

Comment: After a refusal, UKVI will not process a subsequent application on a priority basis. Should you opt, and pay, for priority, your application will be pulled from the queue. No one can predict how long the process will take.

Comment: @Giorgio That looks like an answer :)

Comment: @ZachLipton it is, indeed :), but I think it's also a dupe, which I'm looking for; if I can't find it, I'll answer, in expanded format.

Comment: Perhaps it would be better to spend your money on having a UK immigration lawyer prepare your visa application rather than on priority service.